# Ubuntu Apache2 403 error

Tags: 16.04, apache2, html

So I installed eve seat on my ubuntu os to find that after using the very user friendly installer I get an error 403 when I try to use it. A bit of google searching points at one of the following: missing html page, a php error, a website file config issue, possibly being the cause.

I'm not familiar with a lot of the software behind the scenes of this  to understand what I'm looking at fixing? Please help?

eve seat i installed:
https://github.com/eveseat/seat

Ubuntu 16.04lts x64

Comment: Do you have .htaccess file in the root directory?

Comment: doesn't look like it. I'll get a screenshot of the root/similar to c:/

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxF5-eVBfEeNSUxlaDliQzg1UlU/view?usp=sharing

Is there a way to launch a gui for apache2 where I can stumble about and see if something stands out or if it all looks alien to me and I can't find an issue?

Comment: Is that where the .htaccess file should be and what should be in it?

Answer (score 0):

How did you install it ?

- Manually
- Using installer script ?

You'll be able to find more information into `/var/www/seat/storage/logs/laravel-date.log`

Where

- `/var/www/seat` is the default seat install path
- `date` is the current date

Can you send us your vhost setting file ?

- `/etc/apache2/sites-available/100-seat.local.conf`

Can you show us your active vhost directory ?

- In a terminal, enter `ls -la /etc/apache2/sites-enabled`

Finally, the `.htaccess` is located at `/var/www/seat/public/` again where `/var/www/seat` is the default install directory.